# Laravel detect if error on blade page

Tags: php, laravel

I need to check if Laravel is redirected from failed validation.
If so then I will use the `old()` function, otherwise I will show data from model.

I don't want to check for every input like `old('name')`. I just need a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blade for example:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    {{ old(ˋvalueˋ) }}
@endif
```

or

```
{{ old('value', $model->value) }}
```

Comment: What you also can do, something like {{ old('value', $model->value) }}